# How to Access nested dictionary keys to make a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a set of dictionary objects that has a structure looking like this:

```
{'android_id': 'ds cgethcvwrzvbjezrzve',
 'app': 'hndbfhjdfhf bnmhjknuihklmmkbghjbtfgjnkluilnkkfbnjtkjzn',
 'app_ver': '10.0.1_0',
 'at': '2016-02-02 23:59:47',
 'birth_date': 1447896843,
 'browser': 'Android 4',
 'carrier': 'Comcast Cable',
 'city_name': 'Jacksonville',
 'country': 'us',
 'custom': {'Action': 'Click',
 'Campaign ID': '167713',
 'Creative ID': '113961',
 'Creative Type': 'Alert',
 'Schema Version - Client': '3',
 'Schema Version - Server': '1'},
 'customer_ids': {'customer_id': '1234587612545464525441540341414'},
 'data_conn': 'android_network_type_3',
 'device_new': False,
}
```

My question is. How do I access the nested keys to produce columns in a Pandas DataFrame? I imported from pandas.io.json json_normalize.
and tried, json_normalize(dictionary) but the performance is quite bad because I have about 200,000 entries I would like to normalize. Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the performance if you just loop through the data structure with respect to time? Say if you apply something like: `for entry in data:
    if type(data[entry]) is dict:
        # do something to data[entry]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can un-nest the data then construct your dataframe. Here is how to un-nest it.

```
df = {'android_id': 'ds cgethcvwrzvbjezrzve',
      'app': 'hndbfhjdfhf bnmhjknuihklmmkbghjbtfgjnkluilnkkfbnjtkjzn',
      'app_ver': '10.0.1_0',
      'at': '2016-02-02 23:59:47',
      'birth_date': 1447896843,
      'browser': 'Android 4',
      'carrier': 'Comcast Cable',
      'city_name': 'Jacksonville',
      'country': 'us',
      'custom': {'Action': 'Click',
      'Campaign ID': '167713',
      'Creative ID': '113961',
      'Creative Type': 'Alert',
      'Schema Version - Client': '3',
      'Schema Version - Server': '1'},
      'customer_ids': {'customer_id': '1234587612545464525441540341414'},
      'data_conn': 'android_network_type_3',
      'device_new': False,
        } 

sub_df1 = df.pop('custom')
sub_df2 = df.pop('customer_ids')

df.update(sub_df1)
df.update(sub_df2)


# you can define a function to do this
def un_nest(df):
    sub_df1 = df.pop('custom')
    sub_df2 = df.pop('customer_ids')

    df.update(sub_df1)
    df.update(sub_df2)
    return df
```

This gives output like

```
{'Action': 'Click',
 'Campaign ID': '167713',
 'Creative ID': '113961',
 'Creative Type': 'Alert',
 'Schema Version - Client': '3',
 'Schema Version - Server': '1',
 'android_id': 'ds cgethcvwrzvbjezrzve',
 'app': 'hndbfhjdfhf bnmhjknuihklmmkbghjbtfgjnkluilnkkfbnjtkjzn',
 'app_ver': '10.0.1_0',
 'at': '2016-02-02 23:59:47',
 'birth_date': 1447896843,
 'browser': 'Android 4',
 'carrier': 'Comcast Cable',
 'city_name': 'Jacksonville',
 'country': 'us',
 'customer_id': '1234587612545464525441540341414',
 'data_conn': 'android_network_type_3',
 'device_new': False}
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. Super fast and elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has a utility function, [`pd.io.json.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html),  to do this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.io.json.json_normalize({'android_id': 'ds cgethcvwrzvbjezrzve',
 'app': 'hndbfhjdfhf bnmhjknuihklmmkbghjbtfgjnkluilnkkfbnjtkjzn',
 'app_ver': '10.0.1_0',
 'at': '2016-02-02 23:59:47',
 'birth_date': 1447896843,
 'browser': 'Android 4',
 'carrier': 'Comcast Cable',
 'city_name': 'Jacksonville',
 'country': 'us',
 'custom': {'Action': 'Click',
 'Campaign ID': '167713',
 'Creative ID': '113961',
 'Creative Type': 'Alert',
 'Schema Version - Client': '3',
 'Schema Version - Server': '1'},
 'customer_ids': {'customer_id': '1234587612545464525441540341414'},
 'data_conn': 'android_network_type_3',
 'device_new': False,
})

df.columns
```

Output is

```
      ['android_id', 'app', 'app_ver', 'at', 'birth_date', 'browser',
       'carrier', 'city_name', 'country', 'custom.Action',
       'custom.Campaign ID', 'custom.Creative ID', 'custom.Creative Type',
       'custom.Schema Version - Client', 'custom.Schema Version - Server',
       'customer_ids.customer_id', 'data_conn', 'device_new']
```

Notice how the function created the nested columns you want.  For example: `custom.Action` and `custom.Campaign ID`.

Comment: FYI, this will probably get downvoted because you didn't read the full question. OP clearly states that he tried `json_normalize` but "performance is quite bad".